# O que é o Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-functions, firebase-database

Faz tempo que não mexo com Android e não tive oportunidade de mexer com o Firebase. Porém ele é muito citado nas perguntas do SOPT.

Afinal, o que é o Firebase?

Trata-se de um conjunto de tecnologias?

Quais são seus recursos mais utilizados?

Poder-me-ia apresentá-los?

Comment: Quem negativou poderia dizer em que a pergunta pode ser melhorada?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Firebase é um produto da Google, um conjunto de tecnologias disponíveis em diversas linguagens: Java, Swift, Objective-C, Python, JavaScript (incluindo Node.js), Go, Unity e C++.

Entre suas tecnologias, as principais:

**- Realtime Database**

O Firebase Realtime Database é um banco de dados NoSQL hospedado na nuvem. Com ele, você armazena e sincroniza dados entre os seus usuários em tempo real.

**- Hosting**

Com o Firebase hosting, você implanta facilmente um app da Web de uma única página, uma página de destino de aplicativos para dispositivos móveis ou um Progressive Web App.

**- Cloud Firestore**

O Cloud Firestore é um banco de dados de documentos NoSQL que permite armazenar, sincronizar e consultar dados facilmente para seus aplicativos móveis e da Web - em escala global.

**- Cloud Functions**

Crie funções acionadas por produtos do Firebase, como alterações de dados no Realtime Database, inscrições de novos usuários pelo Auth e eventos de conversão no Analytics.

**- Monitoramento de desempenho**

Receba insights sobre o desempenho do seu app do ponto de vista dos usuários, com rastreamento de desempenho automático e personalizado.

**- Authentication**

O objetivo do Firebase Authentication é facilitar o desenvolvimento de um sistema de autenticação seguro e melhorar a experiência de login e ambientação para os usuários finais. Ele oferece uma solução de identidade completa, compatível com contas de e-mail/senha, autenticação por telefone, login do Google, Twitter, Facebook, GitHub e outros.

**- Cloud Storage**

O Cloud Storage foi criado para ajudar você a armazenar e oferecer conteúdo gerado pelo usuário, como fotos ou vídeos, com facilidade e rapidez.

**- Google AdWords**

Impulsione o número de instalações, receba insights aprofundados sobre conversões de anúncios e exiba campanhas de anúncios segmentados usando os públicos-alvo do Google Analytics for Firebase para interagir com a sua base de usuários.

**- AdMob**

A AdMob by Google é uma plataforma de publicidade móvel que pode ser usada para gerar receita com seu aplicativo. O uso da AdMob com o Google Analytics para Firebase fornece recursos adicionais de dados e recursos de análise de aplicativos. O Firebase integra-se à AdMob sem exigir alterações na configuração existente.

**- Cloud Messaging**

O Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) oferece uma conexão confiável e com baixo consumo de bateria entre servidor e dispositivos para enviar e receber mensagens e notificações no Android, no iOS e na Web sem custo nenhum.

**- Google Analytics**

O Google Analytics para Firebase oferece geração de relatórios gratuita e ilimitada para até 500 eventos diferentes. O SDK captura automaticamente determinados eventos-chave e propriedades do usuário, e você pode definir eventos personalizados e avaliar itens relevantes para o seu negócio.

**Obervação:** Nem todas tecnologias tem suporte para todas plataformas

- [Introdução ao Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?hl=pt-br)
- [Lista com todos produtos](https://firebase.google.com/products/?hl=pt-br)
- [Documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/?hl=pt-br)
- [Preços](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?hl=pt-br), apesar de poder pagar para ter mais funções/armazenamento, a maioria dos produtos possui planos gratuítos

Comment: Vale ressaltar que o serviço de mensageria/_push notification_ da antiga Google Cloud Message (GCM) é considerado obsoleto e eles mesmos recomendam migrar para o Firebase

Comment: FCM não é _deprecated_, pelo contrário. Meu comentário anterior foi devido à mudança que precisei fazer onde trabalhava que foi uma ruptura abrupta com o GCM, colocando o FCM no lugar. Se antes não me fiz claro: FCM == bom, GCM == velho feio e ruim

Comment: Ata agora entendi, nunca usei nenhum dos dois, obrigado. Eles podiam mudar para um nome um pouco diferente